# Port forwarding breaks everything. How do I fix it?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, minecraft, hosting

My home network consists of 2 routers. Router 1(ZyXEL) is connected directly to the outside, router 2(TP-LINK) is connected to router 1 and my PC is connected to router 2. All connections are by cable.

I'm hosting a Minecraft server for my friends therefore I need to port forward. When I connect my PC directly to router 1, my port forwarding works but that means I need to disconnect router 2 from the internet and I have no wifi in the room with my PC for my phone and other wifi devices.

When I tried forwarding my PC to router 2 and router 2 to router 1, the server was accessible but when I tried to connect to the wifi with my phone, it said "Couldn't get IP address". After an hour or so, my PC disconnected from the internet and i couldn't even open the router settings.

The question is how do I make it work with two routers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have both devices in router mode:

1. Router 1 should be the Internet-facing one.
2. Router 2 should be reconfigured as an access point (or similar configuration).

In essence, Router 2 will work as an extension of your network, getting DHCP addresses from Router 1. Every PC and even Router 2 will have an IP address assigned by Router 1.

Once every device has its IP, you can configure port forwarding.

Also, see if your router supports UPnP, it may be simpler to configure than port-forwarding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately, I don't know how to do that. Can you please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: My main/default router has DHCP off and is port forwarded to the internal router. My internal router has DHCP on and is port forwarded to my computer which is hosting the server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).